# Matlab: Daily 3d array to monthly- dealing with alternate days in a month and leap years - How to do it?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

In matlab I have a 720x360x365 matrix (let's call it A) of daily precipitation for one year.  365 stands for days in a year. I need to write a code to convert these daily data to the monthly sum. If I start from January, I need to do mean (A,3) of the first 31 days, then the mean (A,3) of February, the next 28 or 29 days. Because the days alternate between 31 and 30 (and 28 or 29 for February), I don't know how to write a code to do this.
please help me I don't know how to do it.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mat2cell` to divide your data in cells per month. First make a vector with the number of days per month (not taking into account leap years), and then use this to divide the data. Then you can use `cellfun` on each cell (i.e. month) to get any metric you define per month:

```
data =  rand(720, 360, 365);
days_per_month = [31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31];

% divide months in cells
data_cell = mat2cell(data, size(data,1), size(data,2), days_per_month);
mean_cell = cellfun(@(A) mean(A,3), data_cell, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

To use this in a loop, and account for leap years, you can use the function [`leapyear(year)`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/aerotbx/ug/leapyear.html):

```
days_per_month = [31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31];
years = 1984:2015
for k = 1:numel(years)
    if leapyear(years(k))
        days_per_month(2) = 29;
    else
        days_per_month(2) = 28;
    end

    % rest of what you want to do

end
```

Comment: Actually I need to apply your above-mentioned code for 34 years, from 1984 to 2015 by using a loop. so if you could please help me to deal with leap years too.